# Creating a Layout in Java

Tags: java, swing

[I am trying a create a layout like a picture below. I am new to Java programming.]When I am trying to run this. There is no error or anything and nothing displays. Console stops automatically. Kindly help me.

[image: Example]

```
package completeJavaReference; 
import java.awt.FlowLayout; 
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JTextField;
------------------------------------------------------------------------


    public class tryingProject extends JFrame {
        public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;//Eclipse added
        public static JLabel carname;
        public static JLabel price, make, year, trim, category, VIN, model,bodytype;
        public static JLabel dealerinfo, ID, URL, Name;
        public static JTextField priceTextField, makeTextField, yearTextField, 
        trimTextField, categoryTextField, VINTextField, modelTextField, 
        bodytypeTextField;
        private static JTextField dealerinfoTextField, IDTextField, URLTextField, 
        NameTextField;

        public void createComponents() {
            carname = new JLabel("Honda Civic");
            price = new JLabel("Price: ");
            make = new JLabel("Make: ");
            year = new JLabel("Year:");
            trim = new JLabel("Trim:");
            category = new JLabel("Category:");
            VIN = new JLabel("VIN:");
            model = new JLabel("Model:");
            bodytype = new JLabel("Body Type");
            priceTextField = new JTextField(10);
            makeTextField = new JTextField(10);
            yearTextField = new JTextField(10);
            trimTextField = new JTextField(10);
            categoryTextField = new JTextField(10);
            VINTextField = new JTextField(10);
            modelTextField = new JTextField(10);
            bodytypeTextField = new JTextField(10);
            dealerinfo = new JLabel("Dealer Info");
            ID = new JLabel("Dealer ID:");
            URL = new JLabel("URL:");
            Name = new JLabel("Dealer Name");
            dealerinfoTextField = new JTextField(10);
            IDTextField = new JTextField(10);
            URLTextField = new JTextField(10);
            NameTextField = new JTextField(10);
        }
        public void createLayout(){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vehicle Window");
            JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 3));
            JPanel Panel3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            Panel1.add(carname);
            Panel2.add(price);
            Panel2.add(priceTextField);
            Panel2.add(make);
            Panel2.add(makeTextField);
            Panel2.add(year);
            Panel2.add(yearTextField);
            Panel2.add(trim);
            Panel2.add(trimTextField);
            Panel2.add(category);
            Panel2.add(categoryTextField);
            Panel2.add(VIN);
            Panel2.add(VINTextField);
            Panel2.add(model);
            Panel2.add(modelTextField);
            Panel2.add(year);
            Panel2.add(yearTextField);
            Panel3.add(dealerinfo);
            Panel3.add(dealerinfoTextField);
            Panel3.add(ID);
            Panel3.add(IDTextField);
            Panel3.add(URL);
            Panel3.add(URLTextField);
            Panel3.add(Name);
            Panel3.add(NameTextField);
            frame.getContentPane().add(Panel1);
            frame.getContentPane().add(Panel2);
            frame.getContentPane().add(Panel3);
            frame.setTitle("Vechicle Details");
            frame.setSize(200, 200);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
        new tryingProject();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Step back for a minute, have a look at you requirements.  As far as I can see, you have two containers and a label you need to layout at the top level, I would personally focus on understand how to make that work first.  Then take each of the other containers, and break those down and figure out how to make those work

Comment: Sorry to be a party pooper, but before concerning yourself with layouts, you should first work on learning how to create decent OOP-compliant Java classes with non-static instance variables and non-static methods. Your over-use of the static modifier suggests a much more foundational problem than that of which layout is the best to use. Start with the Java tutorial, [Lesson: Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) and move from there.

Comment: yes. I am in phase of studying from basics. But I tried creating a layout something like the picture . Where can be the problem?

Comment: `new tryingProject()` makes a Frame. You never **show** the Frame... And your other methods are also never called... I wouldn't suggest GUI programming to someone new to Java / programming.